# Regex Character Equivalents

Tags: regex, tcl

As documented [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html):

> With the locale set to French, a POSIX-compliant regular expression
>   engine matches **e**, **é**, **è** and **ê** when you use the collating sequence [=e=]
>   in the bracket expression [[=e=]].

I tested `[[=e=]]` in Tcl v8.6 but it only matched `e` characters, however as I understood it should match `é`, `è` & `ê` as well as `e`

Comment: @rid I'm using RegexBuddy v4 for testing

Comment: @rid it has! When it describes regex it's clear: `Match a character from the POSIX equivalence class "e" `

Comment: @rid and also `[éèê]` works as expected.

Comment: @rid I don't like to stick with that kind of solutions where better ones are already existed. Specially when it comes to a language like `Arabic`

Comment: From the [manual](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M46): (*Note*: Tcl implements only the Unicode locale. It does not define any equivalence classes. The examples above are just illustrations.)

Comment: For correct documentation of tcl's implementation of regular expression you should read `man re_syntax`. Also available here: http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm . Note that you can change the tcl version to get the documentation that matches your installed version of tcl. Any other documentation besides this does not apply to tcl's regular expression engine.

Comment: Tcl uses it own regexp engine. It uses a completly different approach than the Perl regexp. See the famous [regexp1](http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) document for the background. It also explains why it is nearly impossible to add backreferences.

Answer (score 1):

The RE engine core supports making sets of characters equivalent in the sense described, but Tcl does not as the only locale that is currently supported in Tcl itself is one where every character is understood to be wholly different to every other character. (Locales are *hard*.)
In short, that's a part of the supported RE syntax that does nothing useful; it should be ignored.

(Note that the documentation you're reading also says that it is not actually implemented usefully.)